# Scanning or reading an image containing optical marks on answer sheets using iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, image-processing, ipad, core-image, omr

What is the best way to get started with OMR processing in iOS?
I need to scan an answer sheet containing marked ovals and process the results using an iphone/ipad?

I am new to this so any help would be great?

http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/omr.htm include SDKS for OMR. But could n't find good documentation on it. Is there a better tool /way to do it?

Should I consider looking into Image processing and detecting oval shapes on the image?

Does iOS provide any framework to support or ease this?

Answer (score 1):

This is Ibrahim from LEADTOOLS support.

We actually have general OCR features, and also specific OMR features. Many of these features, including OMR, are supported in our iOS toolkit.
You can find online copies of all our help topics. The following page contains links to different classes and interfaces related to OCR and OMR:
http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v18/dh/fo/leadtools.forms.ocr~leadtools.forms.ocr_namespace.html

The topics supported on iOS are marked with the small apple icon next to them, such as the IOcrOmrOptions interface.

Furthermore, you can use our free email, live chat or support forums to contact us if you need any details you couldn't find in the help files.